# How do I adjust the mouse sensitivity?

Tags: pc, hotline-miami-2

It just seems the mouse sensitivity is extremely low and seems sluggish.

I have checked the controls menu and that option does not appear to be there.

How do I change the sensitivity of my controls?

Comment: I remember playing HLM1, and finding the same thing. I ended up switching to a gamepad. If that's an option for you, I'd recommend it.

Comment: What computer/gaming system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the mouse sensitivity from the main menu settings, but not from the pause menu settings.

Comment: Also if the horizontal sensitivity differs from the vertical try changing the aspect ratio of the screen.